# How can I debug e-mail sending on Gitlab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab

My Gitlab (version 5) is not sending any e-mails and I am lost trying to figure out what is happening. The logs give no useful information. I configured it to used `sendmail`.

I wrote a small script that sends e-mail through ActionMailer (I guess it is what gitlab uses to send e-mail, right?). And it sends the e-mail correctly.

But, on my Gitlab, I can guarantee that sendmail is not even being called.

Do I need to enable something to get e-mail notifications? How can I debug my issue?

## Update

The problem is that I can not find any information anywhere. The thing just fails silently. Where can I find some kind of log? The logs in the `log` dir provide no useful information.

My question is, how can I make Gitlab be more verbose? How can I make it tell me what is going on?

## Update 2

I just found a lot of mails scheduled on the `Background jobs` section. A lot of unprocessed `Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer`. What does it mean? Why were these jobs not processed?

Comment: Anything in sidekiq log (as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2747)? Note that sidekiq is replaced by puma in 5.1 so it would be interesting to check if the issue persists with the very latest of GitLab.

Comment: Sidekiq log is empty. I will test it with the lastest gitlab from master.

Comment: Still the same issue. The problem is that I can not find any information anywhere. The thing just fails silently. Where can I find some kind of log? The logs in the `log` dir provides no useful information.

Comment: I just found a lot of mails scheduled on the Background jobs section.

Comment: I have same problem. Seems caused by database ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I will tell what was my problem: The sidekiq is responsible for handling sending e-mails. For some reason my sidekiq was stuck, restarting it solved the problem.

Where I found information about problems I found on Gitlab:

1. The logs dir. It has a few informations.
2. On admin page, the section "Background jobs" gives information about the sidekiq.
3. The javascript console (if your browser supports it) also has useful information. Only if your problem is related to javascript.
4. And if you reach this point, you may modify Gitlab's code so you can "trace it" writing to a file:

   `File.open('/tmp/logfile','a') { |file| file.write("Hello World!\n") }`

Answer (score 49):

Stumbled upon this issue today, here's my research:

Debugging SMTP connections in the GitLab GUI is not supported yet. However there is a pending [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/16557#note_18106744) and a [command line solution](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/debug.html).

Set the desired SMTP settings `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` (see https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html).

Start the console running `gitlab-rails console -e production`.

Show the configured delivery method (should be `:smtp`) running the command `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method`. Show all configured SMTP settings running `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings`.

To send a test mail run

```
Notify.test_email('youremail@example.com', 'Hello World', 'This is a test message').deliver_now
```

On the admin page in GitLab, the section »Background jobs« shows information about all jobs. Failing SMTP connections are listed there as well.

Please note, you may need to restart the GitLab instance in order to use the newly configured SMTP settings (on my instance the console was able to send mails, the GUI required a restart). Run `gitlab-ctl restart` to restart your instance.

Comment: Is it possible to directly modify the ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings using the console?

Comment: Afaik No. Docs [don't](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/gitlab.yml.html) [mention](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/architecture/README.html#global-gitlab-configuration-template) something like this and I cant see a command to do so.

Comment: Really useful post, unfortunately I haven't found the issue yet

Comment: I had not found the combination of commands above elsewhere.  Being able to list what Gitlab thinks its STMP configs are and to actually see the response from the SMTP server using the Notify.test_email().deliver_now allowed me to solve my issue with sending mail from an SMTP config not listed in their help docs.  Very helpful!

Comment: The command `gitlab-rails console -e production` and then`Notify.test_email('youremail@example.com', 'Hello World', 'This is a test message').deliver_now` still works for latest version of Gitlab-CE v16.2.4 in 2023

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try enabling delivery errors in production mode and see what happens

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: It is already true. I mean, it is located in `config/environments/production.rb`, right?

Comment: I just found a lot of mails scheduled on the Background jobs section. Do you know what does it means?

Comment: I don't know how gitlab works, but I guess there is something like resque or delayed jobs that runs the background queues .. Maybe those queues are now working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In the admin section under Background Jobs if you have lots of items in the Scheduled tab try restarting `sidekiq`:

```
cd /home/git/gitlab    
exec rake sidekiq:start RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and while I don't recommend tinkering with the GitLab source code, I was able to do my debugging with a mod to `application.rb`:

```
diff --git a/config/application.rb b/config/application.rb
index d85bcab..274976f 100644
--- a/config/application.rb
+++ b/config/application.rb
@@ -11,6 +11,8 @@ end

 module Gitlab
   class Application < Rails::Application
+    config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = { :arguments => "-i" }
+
     # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
     # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
     # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
```

Note:  I'm running Debian 7 which uses exim for mail.

**Update Oct 2023:** I don't expect this to be done to a production environment, and this was done 9 years ago ... before GitLab had the options available that it does today. Please review the GitLab documentation, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hacking at the GitLab source is most certainly not the preferred way, of fixing the problem and it is very specific to YOUR environment.

Comment: While I agree that modifying source code is not desirable, this is "debugging" ... I wouldn't expect it to be left in place in production. It gives people the solution that worked for me, and I don't expect it to work for anybody running a different environment. I'll edit my answer to make that more obvious. 

Comment: I've edited my 9-year-old answer to make my previous point more obvious and help people realize that options for debugging have likely changed since I provided this answer. 